# How to invoke lambda asynchronously from another lambda using serverless framework

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm trying to build out an architecture in Serverless Framework where one Lambda calls another Lambda asynchronously, using the Node.js AWS SDK. I understand that when invoking asynchronously, the calling Lambda will not wait for the called Lambda to run and respond, but instead will get a response from AWS with the status of the invocation itself.

From what I've read, the way to call a Lambda asynchronously is to use the Lambda `invoke()` method with `InvocationType: 'Event'` in the params (as opposed to synchronous invocation with `InvocationType: 'RequestResponse'`). However, it doesn't seem to matter what I set as the `InvocationType`; the second Lambda always runs in full and returns its response to the first, just as if I had set `InvocationType: 'RequestResponse'`.

In my `serverless.yml` file, I have:

```
functions:
  receive_deltas:
    handler: src/record/delta_lambdas.receive
    vpc: ${self:custom.vpc}
    events:
      - http:
          method: post
          path: v1/deltas
  
  process_deltas:
    handler: src/record/delta_lambdas.process
    vpc: ${self:custom.vpc}
```

In my TypeScript handler, I have:

```
import { Lambda } from 'aws-sdk';

export const receive = async (event) => {
  const { recordIds } = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const lambda = new Lambda({
    region: 'us-west-2',
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:3003',
  });

  const params = {
    FunctionName: 'orgconfig-dev-process_deltas',
    InvocationType: 'Event',
    Payload: JSON.stringify({ recordIds }),
  };

  lambda.invoke(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return failureResponse(err);
    } else {
      return parseResponse(data);
    }
  });
};

export const process = async (event) => {
  console.log('running process lambda');

  // process a bunch of stuff

  console.log('finished processing');
};
```

The first Lambda always waits for the second Lambda to run in its entirety, and eventually gets a response of `{ StatusCode: 200, Payload: '' }`. I'm expecting a successful async invocation to return an immediate response with `StatusCode: 202`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

What I was missing, it seems, was that the Serverless Offline plugin—or at least my configuration of it—does not emulate asynchronous lambda invocation in this way. (Note in my Lambda constructor I had a localhost endpoint giving away that it was offline.) Once I deployed to an AWS instance, it worked perfectly.

If anyone has a configuration that's worked for them with Serverless Offline and async Lambda invocation, it might be worth posting here for future internauts.

Answer (score 0):

> a configuration that's worked for them with Serverless Offline and async Lambda invocation, it might be worth posting here for future internauts

Just in case someone's looking for a working config ...

Try **async: true** for both (invoker and invoked) functions in serverless.yml

**InvocationType** should be "Event" in lambda.invoke parameters

**iam role statements** : *lambda:InvokeAsync*

**FunctionName** for offline invocation should come in the format *serviceName-stage-functionName*, so all together it looks like:

```
functions:
  invoker:
  handler: ...your-handler
   environment:
     your_Ref_to_offlineLamName: "${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-invoked"
     events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: ...yourpath
          async: true
   invoked:
     handler: ...somehandler
     events:
      - http:
          method: post
          path: ...somepath
          async: true
```

handler

```
let param = {
      FunctionName: process.env.IS_OFFLINE == "true" ? process.env.your_Ref_to_offlineLamName : "whatever",
      InvocationType: "Event",
      Payload: JSON.stringify({test:"TESTTEST"})
    };
   lambda.invoke(param).promise()
```

tested in node15.
(based on https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline#usage-with-invoke)